# Finding the minimum sum path between two vertices in an undirected weighted graph

Tags: graphs

What algorithm would I use for finding the minimum-weight path between two vertices in an undirected weighted graph?

Dijkstra is for shortest path, but I need path with the minimum sum of the weights. Would Prim's or Kruskal's algorithm do this? Is a brute force method required? There are millions of nodes and edges.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for. Your input is a weighted graph. What's the output supposed to be? A pair of vertices $u,v$ such that the total weight of all $u$-$v$ paths is minimum, compared to other pairs of vertices? That's what your question seems to be asking but your comments on the answer suggest that you were using Dijkstra, which will only tell you the minimum weight path between some pair of vertices, not the sum of all paths between them.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I would like to find the path with the minimum strength (where strength is the some of the weights of the edges) out of all the paths between to vertices. Can this be done with Dijkstra? Or do I need another approach to solving this?

Comment: If all you want is a minimum-weight path, almost any search algorithm will give the correct answer.

Comment: Ok...I suck...I think I have have an issue with my implementation. I'm not getting the minimum path in all cases. I think I misunderstood how the algorithm is supposed to work. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When looking at weighted graphs, "shortest path" usually means "minimal weight path".
[Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is used for finding the shortest (minimal weight) path between nodes in a directed graph with non-negative weights, however, [if there are negative weights it could fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799172/negative-weights-using-dijkstras-algorithm).
[Bellman-Ford algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) is used for the same purpose for graphs with negative weights (and has a slower runtime).

So in your case you need to:

1. Transform your graph into a directed graph (by duplicating each undirected edge $ (u, v) \in E$ into two directed edges $(u, v)$ and $(v, u)$ with the same weight)
2. Choose one of the above algorithms based on the existence of negative weights in the graph

Comment: I don't have negative numbers, but in my scenario's the shortest path is not necessarily the minimal weight path. Does Dijkstra's algorithm handle this case? E.g. A - 2 - B - 8 - C = 10; A -3 - F -1-T -1- E -1- C = 6

Comment: It's a matter of definition. By shortest path you seem to mean "path with least amount of edges", however, when talking about weighted graphs the notion of the amount of edges isn't usually considered.
Either way - Dijkstra would return the path A-F-T-E-C which is what I think you're looking for...

Comment: I am looking for that path, but my Dijkstra's implementation is not returning that. I thought that it looked for the path with the least amount of edges....will look to see if I did something wrong.